# Jquery show counter in for loop

Tags: php, jquery

So I am using a foreach loop (php) and in that loop a jQuery for-loop

here is my code

```
foreach($products as $product):
?>
  var qty = $('#product_<?= $product->id ?>').val();
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < qty; ++i) {
    //remove Item from list
    // alert(i);
    $('#delete_[<?=$product->id?>]['+ i +']').click(function(){
      swal({
          title: "<?= __('Do you really want to delete order No. {0}?', [$product->id]); ?>",
          type: "warning",
      }, function(isConfirm){
          if (isConfirm) {
            alert('delete me');
          }
          else {
              swal("<?= __('The order is canceled') ?>", " ", "error");
          }
      });
    });

    $(wrapper).append(
      ...
      '<div class="actions corner">' +
            '<a id="delete_[<?=$product->id?>]['+ i +']" title="<?= __("Cancel order") ?>" class="user-action-button-delete">' +
                '<i class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></i>' +
            '</a>'+
        '</div>'+
        ...
    );
  }
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

The loop is working but for some reason I don't get the value of the second dimension for div #delete_[1]['+i'] in //remove Item from list

Under this code in "wrapper" element is same process/logic and I am getting value of "i"

Why does the browser parse i like i and not like counter?

thx

---

### One more example

There is pretty same code with same error

```
//Start delete block
<?php
foreach($products as $product):
?>
ar qty = parseFloat($('#product_<?= $product->id ?>').val());
 var i = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < qty; ++i) {
    //Start remove Item from list
       var delete_div = $('#delete-<?=$product->id?>-'+ i);
       var delete_element = $('#preselected-<?=$product->id?>-'+ i);
            delete_div.on('click', function(){
                 swal({
                    title: "<?= __('Do you really want to delete product No. {0}?', [$product->name]); ?>",
                      type: "warning",
                      showCancelButton: true,
                              confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                              confirmButtonText: "<?= __('OK'); ?>",
                              cancelButtonText: "<?= __('Cancel'); ?>",
                              closeOnConfirm: true,
                              closeOnCancel: true
                          }, function(isConfirm){
                              console.log(i);
                          });

                        });

                      }
                  <?php
                  endforeach;
                  ?>
```

Comment: Prepare your string id beforehand and then pass it on to $()

Answer (score 0):

Currently `qty` is getting the value from your input and you are using that to create the upper limit of your loop.This is assuming that is an input or other element that has a value attribute. If its not - you will need to use .text() or .html().

But even if its an input - `qty` will be a string - even a number input returns a string value from .val() so you need to parse the value into a number to be able to use as the iterating count. So `i` is not the problem - it is simplynot incrementing because `qty` is not a number.

```
var qty = parseInt($('#product_<?= $product->id ?>').val());
```

or

```
var qty = parseFloat($('#product_<?= $product->id ?>').val());
```

then qty will be a number that you can use in your for loop:

```
 for (i = 0; i < qty; ++i) {...
```